# Error in fetch and show in angular datatable

Tags: angularjs, json, datatable, datatables

Jquery Datatable Value Insertion :--
how can we fetch and store data table values.?

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at jquery.dataTables.min.js:45
    at i (jquery.dataTables.min.js:32)
    at Object.success (jquery.dataTables.min.js:32)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
```

> i am getting error when going to show data in jquery datatable what would be the reason behind this?

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="datatables.bootstrap.css">
<script>  
    var myAngApp = angular.module('myApp', ['datatables']);  
    myAngApp.controller('feedbackController', ['$scope','$http','DTOptionsBuilder','DTColumnBuilder',function ($scope,$http,DTOptionsBuilder,DTColumnBuilder){  


          $scope.vm={};
            $scope.vm.dtColumns = [
           DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(0).withTitle('Feedback Id'),
           DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(1).withTitle('Feedback Action Id'),
           DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(2).withTitle('Description'),
           DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(3).withTitle('Email'),
           DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(4).withTitle('Created Date')
       ]

       $scope.vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('ajax',{
            method: 'GET',
            dataSrc:"aaData",  
            url: "http://localhost:8080/feedback/webapi/Feedbacks"
      })
      .withOption('pocessing',true)
      .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
      }]

      );   
</script>
```

Comment: Since this is angular the <markup> is really important as well.

Comment: @davidkonrad thanks. but sorry to say i have not  got what you said. could you please explain it so that it will be helpful for me.

Comment: Hey @Anshu, just meant the HTML that correspond to the javascript. Your <table....> code.

Comment: @davidkonrad thank you so much...